# Connect Docker running on MAC

Tags: macos, docker, windows-10, virtual-machine, docker-machine

I am trying to connect docker running on MacOS. I have a Windows 10 VM running on Mac and instead of installing docker again in VM(which usually runs in many issues), I'd like to connect to docker running on Mac. Can someone point me to a tutorial or some answer. I am novice in docker.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already installed [Docker Desktop for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/)?

After you've got Docker up and running, tell it where your projects are:

1. Open Docker Preferences
2. Click the File Sharing icon in the icon bar at the top of the window
3. Click the plus button at the bottom of the path list
4. Select the folder that contains all your projects
5. Click Apply & Restart

If you need to have your Windows VM connect to your Docker containers running on macOS, you'll need find out if Windows can access your Mac via networking. You will also need to modify your Windows `hosts` file to point to your Mac's IP address.